# Which target to patch when using a mysql.connector database connection?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, dependency-injection, mocking

Patching a database queries:

import mysql.connector
    from flask import g

```
@before_request
def con():  
    g.db=mysql.connector.connect("credentials")  #database connection

@route('/insert')   #passing data for insertion  as a 'json' string
def insert():
    cursor = g.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('Insert into  test("ID,name")')
    cursor.close()
    g.db.close()
```

test.py

```
def test_conn():
 with patch(app.mysql.connector) as mock_mysql:
  conn()
  mock_mysql.connect.assert_called_with("credentials")

def test_insert():
 with patch(target =?) as mock:
  #mock execute() and close()?
```

Do I have to patch my (`conn()` and `g`) or (`mysql.connector` and `g`) as a target?

How to mock `execute()` and `close()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock `mysql.connector.connect` here, and the mock library takes over from there:

```
with patch(target='mysql.connector.connect') as mock:
```

The code then calls the `connect` mock, returning a *new* mock object stored in `g.db`. You can reach those objects in your test function:

```
connection = mock.return_value
cursor = connection.cursor.return_value
```

and then you can test if `connection.close` and `cursor.execute` and `cursor.close` have been called.

Comment: Thanks for a help,but don't you think i also need to patch 'g' because  it is  a library imported form Flask  otherwise code will going to call a 'g' library

Comment: @guri: Just use the Flask test tools, such as the test client or test request context; see http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/